# Convert netCDF into CSV using python

Tags: python, netcdf, netcdf4, python-iris

I am new to Python and trying to parse the netCDF file into .CSV in columanar format, so I can load that data into RDBMS for other reporting purpose. Please refer the details below.

Sanpshot of my netCDF file:

```
dimensions:
time = UNLIMITED ; // (36 currently)
grid_latitude = 548 ;
grid_longitude = 421 ;
time_0 = UNLIMITED ; // (3 currently)
pressure = 3 ;
time_1 = UNLIMITED ; // (3 currently)
bnds = 2 ;
pressure_0 = 2 ;
pressure_1 = 3 ;
dim0 = UNLIMITED ; // (3 currently)
grid_longitude_0 = 421 ;
grid_latitude_0 = 547 ;
time_3 = UNLIMITED ; // (3 currently)
variables:
float stratiform_snowfall_rate(time, grid_latitude, grid_longitude) ;
stratiform_snowfall_rate:_FillValue = -1.073742e+09f ;
string stratiform_snowfall_rate:long_name = "stratiform_snowfall_rate" ;
string stratiform_snowfall_rate:units = "kg m-2 s-1" ;
string stratiform_snowfall_rate:um_stash_source = "m01s04i204" ;
string stratiform_snowfall_rate:grid_mapping = "rotated_latitude_longitude" ;string stratiform_snowfall_rate:coordinates = "forecast_period forecast_reference_time" ;int rotated_latitude_longitude ;
```

My Code:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset, num2date
filename ='prods_op_mogreps-uk_20140717_03_11_015.nc'
nc = Dataset(filename, 'r', Format='NETCDF4')
 ncv = nc.variables
 lats = nc.variables['grid_latitude'][:]
 lons = nc.variables['grid_longitude'][:]
 sfc= nc.variables['stratiform_snowfall_rate'][:]
 times = nc.variables['time'][:]
 units = nc.variables['time'].units
 dates = num2date (times[:], units=units, calendar='365_day')
 header = ['Latitude', 'Longitude']
 for d in dates:
    header.append(d)
import csv
with open('output.csv', 'wb') as csvFile:
    outputwriter = csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter=',')
    for time_index, time in enumerate(times): # pull the dates out for the header
         t = num2date(time, units = units, calendar='365_day')
         header.append(t)
    outputwriter.writerow(header)  
    for lat_index, lat in enumerate(lats):
        content = lat
        #print lat_index
        for lon_index, lon in enumerate(lons):
            content.append(lon)
            #print lon_index    
            for time_index, time in enumerate(times): # for a date
                # pull out the data 
                data = sfc[time_index,lat_index,lon_index]
                content.append(data)
                outputwriter.writerow(content)
csvFile.close()
nc.close()
```

I am getting below error:

> ---
>
> ```
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-41-b4b3b888999f> in <module>
>       4          t = num2date(time, units = units, calendar='365_day')
>       5          header.append(t)
> ----> 6     outputwriter.writerow(header)
>       7     for lat_index, lat in enumerate(lats):
>       8         content = lat
>
> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
> ```

Please help me on this code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You open your output file in binary mode by choosing `'wb'`.
Therefore the file writing function expects binary data, i.e. a `bytes` object.

However, as you're requesting help for writing a csv-file, I assume you want to write plain text data, so you simply should remove the `b` for binary here:

```
with open('output.csv', 'w') as csvFile:
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method for this would be to use xarray and pandas.

```
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd
```

You will first need to read in the data using xarray:

```
data = xr.open_dataset(filename)
```

This will then need to be converted to a pandas dataset, with the index reset:

```
data_df = data.to_dataframe().reset_index()
```

Finally, you would need to save this as a csv:

```
data_df.to_csv(outfile)
```